# How do I make F# execute a method just once?

Tags: f#

I would like to define a type such as:

```
type blah =
     AThing
   | AnotherThing
   with 
     static member ofString : string -> blah
     override x.ToString () : string
```

I would like to make sure that the two methods are always guaranteed to be consistent. A good way of doing this would be to construct two maps from the same list of pairs, and then turn them into the obvious implementations of the two methods. Roughly:

```
let pairs = [Athing, "AThing"; AnotherThing, "AnotherThing"]
let tostr = Map.ofList pairs
let toblah = pairs |> List.map swap |> Map.ofList
```

I think this code can only be defined in a static member function. The static bit is implied by it needing to be accessible from ofString, which is static. It cannot be defined before the type, since the list relies on it. It cannot be defined afterwards because F# does not allow methods to be just declared and implemented later (in the same way that e.g. C++ would). So that leaves the choice between a static member and a static let. The compiler says that static lets are not allowed in an augmentation. (?)

The code works fine when put into a static member function, however it makes the maps every time they are needed. Needless to say, this is even less efficient than linear search. How do I do it correctly please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code that works as required:

```
type blahFactory() =
    static let pairs = printf "array initialized; "; [AThing, "AThing"; AnotherThing, "AnotherThing"]
    static member tostr = Map.ofList pairs
    static member toblah = pairs |> List.map swap |> Map.ofList
and blah =
    | AThing
    | AnotherThing
    with
    static member ofString (string) = blahFactory.toblah.[string]
    override x.ToString () = blahFactory.tostr.[x]
```

I've placed `printf` instruction to demonstrate the array is initialized just once.

Several thoughts you may consider useful.
First, using DU is overhead for sample provided. If your data is that simple, you may consider `enum` types.
If you really mean DU, that may be sign of possible problems in the future. Consider this:

```
type blah =
    | AThing of string
    | AnotherThing of int * int
```

Both construction and comparison will be impossible in this case.

Do you have any reasons not to use standard XML serialization?

Comment: Many thanks, that seems to be the best solution. I am not sure why enums should be that different efficiency-wise? My parser reads an XML file written by some C++ code. I need both executables to work under Linux, and AFAIK there is no Linux .net C++ compiler. I expect this rules out the use of whatever is the standard XML serialization. My design is basically a recursive descent parser using the Linq XElement and active patterns. It seems a great improvement over Xerces, though the stack usage is best not thought about. Anything in here that sounds a daft choice, please do let me know.

Answer (score 3):

This compiles (with a warning)

```
type blah = 
     AThing 
   | AnotherThing 

let pairs = [AThing, "AThing"; AnotherThing, "AnotherThing"] 
let tostr = Map.ofList pairs 
let toblah = pairs |> List.map (fun (x,y)->y,x) |> Map.ofList 

type blah
   with  
     static member ofString s = toblah.[s]
     override x.ToString () = tostr.[x]
```

and demonstrates an augmentation (define the type, do other code, then do `type blah with` to define more members).

Answer (score 2):

I don't get your point. What's wrong with:

```
type blah =
   | AThing
   | AnotherThing
   with 
     static member ofString = function
            | "AThing" -> AThing
            | "AnotherThing" -> AnotherThing
            | _ -> failwith "Unwellformed string"

     override x.ToString () =
            match x with
            | AThing -> "AThing"
            | AnotherThing -> "AnotherThing"
```

Pattern matching is Θ(1) which is extremely efficient in F#.

Comment: It is not at all clear that ToString () |> ofString is the identity, especially once there are many cases. I suspect the claim that pattern matching is O(1) is unlikely to be relevant. I want something O(log n) in the number of clauses. It may be that F# achieves that, but I don't see there is a guarantee. In any case, that would be the asymptotically optimal complexity expressed in a useful way. I am sure you can defend the O(1) claim in the same way that someone could who implemented Knapsack in unary. Except conversion to unary is easily automated, whereas here I'd have to do the typing :-)

Comment: Pattern matching against strings that are not interned is not Θ(1) since no such algorithm exists to do a search in O(1).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you were trying to do the following: for any Discriminated Union have an ability to go from  particular DU case to its name and back without burden of hardcoding the relationship for each pair, which have place in both answers by Brian and pad.

If you sacrifice override of ToString() in lieu of the equivalent static member it can be done with the following approach:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
type Blah =
    | AThing
    | AnotherThing

[<AutoOpenAttribute>]
module BlahExt =
    let cases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<Blah>
    let toBlah = dict [for case in cases do yield (case.Name, FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case, [||]) :?> Blah)]
    let fromBlah = dict [for case in cases do yield ((FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case, [||]) :?> Blah), case.Name)]
    type Blah     
    with
        static member ofString name =
            if toBlah.ContainsKey name then (toBlah.Item name) else failwith "bad string"
        static member toString x = fromBlah.Item x
```

Now `printfn "ofString: %A" (Blah.ofString "AThing")` shows union case `AThing` and vice versa `printfn "toString: %s" (Blah.toString AThing)` shows string `AThing`.

You can notice that I did not list members of your DU whatsoever, this is achieved once thru reflection and guaranteed to be correct mapping automagically. This approach will work **for any number of unit cases** - two or two hundreds - without any need to hardcode the particular cases.

Comment: Many thanks for that. It is a very good solution, but the ofString function is needed for parsing an XML file, so the string values will change over time (and I would rather this did not require a change to the source code beyond changing the affected string). However, your solution is something I did not think of, so this is a very helpful learning experience.